# I want last line of code (sp500.plot) to graph pulled data, why doesn't the last line work?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with creation of the graph and need explanation.

I have code:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pull sp data from yahoo finance
sp500 = yf.download('^GSPC', start='2010-6-1', end='2020-5-25') 

#calc log rtn using close price
sp500['Log_Ret'] = np.log(sp500['Close'] / sp500['Close'].shift(1)) 

#calc vol using pandas rolling Std Dev
sp500['Volatility'] = sp500['Log_Ret'].rolling(window=252).std() * np.sqrt(252)
print(sp500.tail(40))
```

this line should create a graph however it doesn't. Can someone explain why?

```py
sp500[['Close', 'Volatility']].plot(subplots=True, color='blue', figsize=(8,6))
```

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get an error message? Or just "nothing"?

Comment: hey, literally nothing, the 2nd to last line pulls the data i want, but the last line of code sp500.plot doesn't translate the data onto a chart

Comment: is a `plt.show()` statement missing?

Comment: just added plt.show() which has now spat out what I expected, i did add that in previoulsy but got an error message saying "plt isn't defined". however your suggestion has fixed the issue! many thanks!

Comment: Nice. Sounds like previously the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` statement had been missing ...